# Get request parameter values in JSF

Tags: java, jsf

I have a `<odc:tabbedPanel/>` component. Inside this I have a page in the `<odc:bfPanel/>` component.  I want to access a value (of a inputtext or radiobutton) from the page in the `<odc:bfPanel/>` in my `<odc:tabbedPanel/>` managed bean class. Please guide me as to how do I go about this. Please note here that I do not want to use the session here. I want it in request only. I have tried the below options but they didn't work for me.

option one

```
String value = (String) ctx.getExternalContext()
                        .getRequestParameterValuesMap()
                        .get("managedbean.property");
```

option two

```
String value = (String) ctx.getExternalContext()
                         .getRequestParameterValuesMap()
                         .get("property");
```

option three

```
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                         .getExternalContext().getRequest();
System.out.println(req.getParameter("property"));
```

option four

```
Map requestMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() 
                         .getExternalContext().getRequestHeaderValuesMap(); 
String msgId = (String) requestMap.get("property"); 
System.out.println(msgId);
```

option five

```
HttpServletRequestWrapper r = new HttpServletRequestWrapper(req);
String value1 = r.getParameter("managedbean.property");
```

---

i want the value not in the jsp's managed bean ... but i want it in some another managed bean. here i have pages inside a page(as i had mentioned its a tabbed panel). now i want the value in the managed bean of the outer tab –

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Let first explain why the options you tried did not work:

Option 1 and 2 are invalid because it returns values(!!) as a `String[]`, not a single value as `String`.

Option 3 should work if the parameter was there. But this is not a nice JSF-ish way.

Option 4 is invalid because the parameters are not set in the request header.

Option 5 is invalid because it simply makes no sense. You're only adding an extra abstract layer in between which in fact doesn't change anything here.

---

The JSF-ish way would be the using [`ExternalContext#getRequestParameterMap()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequestParameterMap%28%29):

```
Map<String, String> parameterMap = (Map<String, String>) externalContext.getRequestParameterMap();
String param = parameterMap.get("paramName");
```

As to why option 3 does not work is likely because the parameter name is not what you think/expect it is. JSF namely prepends (woodstocks) client ID's based on parent `UINamingContainer` components in the view tree. Rightclick the generated HTML output of the JSF page in your webbrowser and choose *View Source*. Examine the name of the generated `<input>` element of interest. Use *that* name instead as parameter name.

---

That said, this is after all a workaround not a solution. But we can't reasonably suggest the *real* solution since the functional requirement and the code you have are not fully clear. You normally bind the input elements to a backing bean. If you're actually inside a different backing bean, then you can also just access *that* backing bean from inside the backing bean and then in turn access the input value bound with it. See [Injecting Managed Beans in each other](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/communication-in-jsf.html#InjectingManagedBeansInEachOther) for an how to.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that your controls are inside IBM ODC panels is not relevant.

Usually, you would bind the input control to a managed bean value.

Bean definition:

```
<managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>demo</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>foo.MyManagedBean</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

View tags:

```
<!-- needs to be inside a form control -->
<h:inputText value="#{demo.foo}" />
<h:commandButton value="Click Me" action="#{demo.invokeMe}" />
```

Bean:

```
package foo;
public class MyManagedBean {
  private String foo;
  public String getFoo() { return foo; }
  public void setFoo(String foo) { this.foo = foo; }

  public String invokeMe() {
    System.out.println(foo);
    return null; //no navigation
  }
}
```

If you wanted to bind your input control to a different bean to the one with the application logic, you can use property injection to refer to the other bean.

```
<managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>demo</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>foo.MyManagedBean</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
  <managed-property>
    <property-name>propName</property-name>
    <value>#{someExpression}</value>
  </managed-property>
</managed-bean>
```

*You can look stuff up directly via the context, or use the expression classes to resolve stuff via code, but this is a cleaner approach.*

Comment: i want the value not in the jsp's managed bean ... but i want it in some another managed bean. here i have pages inside a page(as i had mentioned its a tabbed panel). now i want the value in the  managed bean of the outer tab

Comment: @tejas-a - use a `managed-property` to inject the property from one bean into the other - see the last section.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly your question. If the `inputtext` or `radiobutton` is correctly bound to a value in a backing bean, then you can access the value directly in Java. If what you are interested in is the programmatic lookup of a managed bean, then that's how I do it:

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
MyBean currentProperty = (MyBean) facesContext.getELContext().getELResolver().getValue(facesContext.getELContext(), null, "nameOfTheBackingBean");
```