# multiple values in inputText? (JSF)

Tags: java, jsf

Is there a way to associate the return value of an inputText with more than one attrribute?

Like this (it's a sample, value1 and value2 tag attributes does not exist in the syntax):

```
<h:inputText id="matricula" 
             value1="#{alunoController.aluno.matricula}" 
             value2="#{alunoHasCursoController.alunoHasCurso.matricula}">
</h:inputText>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `value` is a predefined attribute in the framework. You can't define your own attributes as `value1,value2...` and did you try to keep this format in your page and check?

Comment: This is a code smell. I don't believe the capability exists and for good reason. It's sloppy design.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just pass inputText value directly to bean method ([described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11941943/pass-input-text-value-to-bean-method)) and in this method you can associate it to multiple variables/fields.

Comment: I will explain deeply my problem> I have two models: Student and Student_has_Course

Both models have the attribute registration.

I need to make both models have this attribute registration set with the same value, received by the inputText. Or there is a way of inside one model, access another to catch the value without reinstantiate it?

Comment: @JohannGomes, please explain the concrete problem in the actual question

Answer (score 0):

Use an `f:valueChangeListener` to cause the changes to be sent to the second bean.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<h:inputText
    value1="#{alunoController.aluno.matricula}" 
    value2="#{alunoHasCursoController.alunoHasCurso.matricula}">
```

Why do you need copies? This is bad design. Java is object oriented and allows you to reference a single object instance by multiple references.

You just need to ensure that `#{alunoHasCursoController.alunoHasCurso}` references exactly the very same `#{alunoController.aluno}` instance.

E.g.

```
public class AlunoHasCursoController {

    @ManagedProperty("#{alunoController.aluno}")
    private Aluno alunoHasCurso;

    // ...
}
```

So that you can get away with

```html
<h:inputText
    value="#{alunoController.aluno.matricula}">
```

Or the other way round, depending on the context and functional requirement.