# Pass value to another component on JSF

Tags: jsf

I am trying to use the value of a text area as a parameter to a button action. I figured out the way to pass parameters to the backing bean but I cannot figure out how to use a value of another field as a parameter. The code I have so far is the following:

```
<h:form>
    <p:inputTextarea id="idHere" label="label"/>

    <p:commandButton value="Register" action="#{contl.register}">
        <f:param name="key" value="????" />
    </p:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

So I am able to get the `"????"` at the backing bean but I am wondering how to use the value of the `inputTextarea` instead. can I somehow use the ID of the field as a reference?

Comment: Which of those duplicates does answer your actual needs? http://stackoverflow.com/q/3681123 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/11941943? Do note that there's quite a difference in the approach and that the first link shows the "natural" approach (as documented in sane references/books/tutorials) and the second link shows the "unnatural" approach (as implied by your question).

Comment: I have already tried the first one without luck but I will give both another go

Comment: If the first one didn't work, you'd need to take a step back and provide the problem in MCVE flavor as instructed in http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info. My educated guess would be that you used the wrong bean management annotations and/or that webapp's runtime classpath is messed up with duplicate different versioned libraries conflicting each other.

Comment: No worries. It worked this time. Maybe I was not quite doing what I should have. Thanks for the links anyway